# IE doesn't show FA icons via https

Tags: internet-explorer, https, font-awesome

There is an AngularJS application which uses FA icons like this:

```
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x"></i>
```

This html works fine everywhere except IE by HTTPS. It also works fine for IE by http. But in IE via http it doesn't show. In IE developer console it looks like next:

[image]

Does anyone have some ideas about root of my issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```